# Why is order of expressions in if statement important

Tags: java, c++, c, if-statement

Suppose I have an `IF` condition :

```
if (A || B) 
    ∧
    |
    |
   left
{ 
   // do something  
}
```

Now suppose that `A` is more likely to receive a true value then `B` , why do I care which one is on the left ?

If I put both of them in the `IF` brackets , then I know (as the programmer of the code) that both parties are needed .

The thing is , that my professor wrote on his lecture notes that I should put the "more likely variable to receive a true" on the left .

Can someone please explain the benefit ? okay , I put it on the left ... what am I gaining ? run time ?

Comment: Just remember if your condition is OR put the condition more likely to be TRUE first, because that is enough to know that all the condition is gonna be true. if your condition is an AND put the condition that is gonna be FALSE first because that is enough to have all your condition false. Java also let you evaluate both conditions (not short circuited) using '|' and '&' operators.

Comment: @gersonZaragocin - the `|` and `&` operators in Java (and C and C++) are bitwise operators. For boolean values they happen to act as you describe, but that's not their purpose.

Comment: @PeteBecker This operators in JLS are refered as "bitwise and logical" operators. Please check this section, they are defined at the end http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22. It is a clear example of operator overloading.

Comment: @gersonZaragocin - thanks. For boolean types they are documented to do logical operations, and that works because boolean values are 1 and 0; they still do bitwise operations. However, for other types, they don't give the same result as `||` or `&&', which was my point.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Its not just about choosing the most likely condition on the left. You can also have a safe guard on the left meaning you can only have one order.  Consider

```
if (s == null || s.length() == 0) // if the String is null or empty.
```

You can't swap the order here as the first condition protects the second from throwing an NPE.

Similarly you can have

```
if (s != null && s.length() > 0) // if the String is not empty
```

The reason for choosing the most likely to be true for `||` or false for `&&` is a micro-optimisation, to avoid the cost of evaluated in the second expression. Whether this translates to a measurable performance difference is debatable.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this a couple more - correctness is a more important consideration than 'which is more likely' regarding operand placement with short circuit operators.  Also - nice real-world examples; the second one is especially important for a novice to understand, since it's a very common idiom.

Answer (score 9):

> **I put it on the left ... what am I gaining ? run time** ?

Because `||` operator in C++ uses ***[short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)***.
 i.e: `B` is evaulated only if `A` is evaluated to a `false`.

However, note that in C++ short-circuit evaluation is guaranteed for *"built in"* data types and not custom data types.

Comment: @ron What else are you talking about?

Comment: @ron - I suspect that this is exactly what your professor means.

Comment: @Als: Okay , so basically , the answer is run-time! got it .

Comment: @ron The difference is not just runtime.  The `||` and `&&` operators are also a kind of control structure.  Think of this (not very good) code: `if (a || this_will_crash_if_a_is_true())`.  When you run it with `a == 1`, there is no crash: the "crashy" function is never called because of short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: Short-circuit evaluation is guaranteed for the built-in operator `||` and operator `&&`, regardless of the data type. You don't get short-circuit evaluation for a user-defined data type that **overloads** those operators, since the overloaded operator is a normal function, and both arguments have to be passed to that function.

Answer (score 5):

As per [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

> The && and || operators perform Conditional-AND and Conditional-OR operations on two boolean expressions. These operators exhibit "short-circuiting" behavior, which means that the second operand is evaluated only if needed

So, if true statement comes first in the order, it short-circuits the second operand at runtime.

Comment: true short-circuits for `||`, not for `&&`. false short-circuits for `&&`, not for `||`.

Answer (score 2):

If the expression on the left is true, there is no need to evaluate the expression on the right, and so it can be optimized out at run time. This is a technique called short-circuiting. So by placing the expression more likely to be true on the left, we can expect our program to perform better than if it were the other way around.

Comment: Describing short-circuit evaluation as an optimization implies that it is optional.  It is not.  It is the behavior mandated by the standard.

Answer (score 2):

You should place the condition that is more likely to be true first because that will cause the if statement to short-circuit. Meaning it will not evaluate the rest of the if statement because it will already know the answer is true. This makes code more efficient.

This is especially useful when your if statement is evaluating expensive things:

```
if(doExpensiveCheck1() || doExpensiveCheck2()) { }
```

In this case cause the checks are expensive it is in your benefit to place the most likely check first.

Answer (score 2):

In many cases there is no practical difference apart from a tiny performance improvement. Where this becomes useful is if your checks are very expensive function calls (unlikely) or you need to check things in order. Say for example you want to check a property on something and to check if that something is nil first, you might do something like:

If (a != nil &&  a.attribute == valid)
{}

Answer (score 0):

Yes exactly, you're gaining runtime, it won't seem much for one operation, but you have to keep in mind that operations will get repeated millions of times

Why perform two evaluations when one is enough is the logic

Answer (score 0):

At runtime if(a||b) will test a first, if a is true it will not waste time testing b therefor the compiler will be 1 execution ahead. Therefore if a is more likely to be true than b this test is also likely to cut 1  line. The total number of lines not executed is tiny on a single line but it’s huge if the statement is nested in a loop of some sort(for,while ,recession or database related queries  ).  Eg per say we have 1million mins to test data in a database at 1 minute per record (30sec for condition A and 30 sec for condition B). Let A have 80% chances to be true and B have 20% chances to be true. The total time needed if you put A first is 600-000hrs yet it’s 900-000hrs if you put  B first.if A is tested first[(0,8*1millions hours)*0,5mins+(0,2*1million hours)*1min]===6000-000hrs : if B is tested first [(0,2*1million hours)*0,5mins+(0,2*1million hours)*1min]===9000-000hrs. However you will notice the difference is less significant if the probability of A becoming true is closer to that of B.

Comment: This is _short circuiting_ and already covered in one of the answers

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        Integer a = null;
        Integer b = 3;
        Integer c = 5;

        if(a != null && a == 2){
            System.out.println("both");
        }else{
            System.out.println("false");
        }
    }
}
```

Hello World
false